# Spark: task not serializable strange error

Tags: apache-spark, serialization

This doesn't work and complains about serialization problems:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import scala.util.Try
import java.net.URLDecoder

import spark.implicits._

val df = List("http%3A%2F%2Fforum.krasmama.ru%2Fviewforum.php%3Ff%3D247").toDF("URL")

def parseURL(s: String): String = {
    Try(URLDecoder.decode(s, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())).toOption.getOrElse(null)
}

val parseURLudf = udf[String, String](parseURL)

val myCond = col("URL").startsWith("http")
val df2 = df.filter(myCond)
val dfWithParsedUrl = df2.withColumn("URL", parseURLudf(col("URL")))
dfWithParsedUrl.show(5, truncate=30)
```

but if I eliminate the `myCond` variable and paste `col("URL").startsWith("http")` directly into `filter`, it works, but why?

Here's the error log:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:340)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:330)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2294)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:841)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:840)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:840)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:311)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:661)
  ... 53 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: startswith(URL, http))
    - field (class: $iw, name: myCond, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@720343cf)
    - field (class: $anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $anonfun$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2, name: func$2, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(input[0, string, false]))
    - element of array (index: 2)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 3)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, <function2>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:337)
  ... 82 more
```

Btw, I don't know if this can be reproduced locally, because in that case Spark doesn't necessarily serialize anything? (In case it only serializes when it needs to send code from driver to executors, sorry, I don't know the details of how it works).

Comment: What is the serialization exception message returned to you ?

Comment: On first view, I'd say `val myCond = col("URL").startsWith("http")` uses a `val` declaration. You're guessing that you're receiving a boolean but it's not the case ? What is the content of `myCond` variable and it's type if you print them on screen ?

Comment: The type of myCond is Column. The error message I will add to my question